# Why can't 'kotlin.Result' be used as a return type?

Tags: function, kotlin, return-type

I've created a method, and the return is `Result<R>` in a class of `MyClass<R>`, but the error message is: 'kotlin.Result' cannot be used as a return type

I've also looked into the Result source code for some hints; why is this so?

[Test code](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/ueeogpr0cqnovot7o4ooa42dv5/l9qidpqj9pf1i7rablka4u5qjt) (using v. 1.3-RC).

```
class MyClass<R>(val r: R) {
    fun f(): Result<R> { // error here
        return Result.success(r)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val s = Result.success(1)
    val m = MyClass(s)   
}
```

Comment: Show us your code that causes the error. Where does `kotlin.Result` come from? I cannot find that class in the [standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/index.html).

Comment: Try kotlin 1.3 or newer

Comment: The limitations on Kotlin Result type are lifted in version 1.5, you can freely use the type as a return type.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

From the [Kotlin KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md#limitations):

> The rationale behind these limitations is that future versions of
> Kotlin may expand and/or change semantics of functions that return
> Result type and null-safety operators may change their semantics when
> used on values of Result type. In order to avoid breaking existing
> code in the future releases of Kotin and leave door open for those
> changes, the corresponding uses produce an error now. Exceptions to
> this rule are made for carefully-reviewed declarations in the standard
> library that are part of the Result type API itself.

**Note:** if you just want to experiment with the `Result` type you can bypass this limitation by supplying a Kotlin compiler argument `-Xallow-result-return-type`.

**When using Gradle on Java or Android project:**
Define the compiler argument on Kotlin compilation task. It applies both for production code and tests.

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + "-Xallow-result-return-type"
    }
}
```

**When using Gradle on Multiplatform project:**
Define the compiler argument for each target compilation. It applies both for production code and tests.

```
kotlin {
    targets.all {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + "-Xallow-result-return-type"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add a snippet about how it can be done in gradle?

Comment: the ['future advancements' section of that KEEP](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md#future-advancements) explains some of the potential breaking changes that motivated these limitations

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a different implementation of the Result type provided by 
https://github.com/michaelbull/kotlin-result
or
https://github.com/kittinunf/Result

Comment: Please help a dummy understand what the !@#$ that rationale means. Anything can change in future versions. Why is Result special?

Answer (score 46):

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xallow-result-return-type"]
    }
}
```

If you using android this solution for gradle

Comment: Kotlin DSL: `freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xallow-result-return-type")`

Answer (score 9):

If using maven:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xallow-result-return-type</arg>
        </args>
    </configuration>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
```

If using gradle:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xallow-result-return-type"]


}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xallow-result-return-type"]
}
```

Source: http://rustyrazorblade.com/post/2018/2018-12-06-kotlin-result/

Answer (score 8):

Update the kotlin version to 1.5 or above. See:

[image: Screenshot of proposal]
https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md#limitations-legacy