# Kotlin Android Retrofit 2.6.0 with coroutines error handling

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.6.0 with coroutines for my web service call. I am getting the API response properly with all response codes (success & error cases). My Issue is when I disconnect the internet(Wifi/mobile data) in between an API call, from the code that I have written, the error is not getting caught properly. The errors most of the time are ConnectException and SocketException.

I have tried to catch the error using interceptor and also in from the ViewModel where initiated my call as well. but here as well, the exception is not getting caught and handled.

```
//ApiService
@GET(ApiUrl.API_DASHBOARD)
    suspend fun getHomeUiDetails(@Header("Authorization") authHeader: String): Response<HomeDetailsResponse>

//ConnectionBridge
suspend fun getHomeUiDetails(authToken: String): Response<HomeDetailsResponse> {
        return ApiServiceGenerator.BASIC_CLIENT_CONTRACT.getHomeUiDetails(authToken)
    }

// ViewModel
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   val apiResponse = ApiConnectionBridge.getHomeUiDetails(SharedPrefUtils.getAuthToken(context))
        if (apiResponse.isSuccessful) {
           // success case
        } else {
            // error case
        }
}

object ApiServiceGenerator {

    val BASIC_CLIENT_CONTRACT: ApiService = ApiClient
        .getContract(
            ApiService::class.java,
            true,
            BuildConfig.BASE_URL
        )
}

object ApiClient {

    fun <T> getContract(clazz: Class<T>, isAuth: Boolean, baseUrl: String): T {
        return getRetrofitBuilder(baseUrl, getContractBuilder(isAuth)).create(clazz)
    }

    private fun getRetrofitBuilder(baseUrl: String, builder: OkHttpClient.Builder): Retrofit {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val original = chain.request()

                // Customize the request
                val request = original.newBuilder()
                request.header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

                var response: Response? = null
                try {
                    response = chain.proceed(request.build())
                    response.cacheResponse()

                    // Customize or return the response

                    response!!
                } catch (e: ConnectException) {
                            Log.e("RETROFIT", "ERROR : " + e.localizedMessage)
                    chain.proceed(original)
                } catch (e: SocketException) {
                    Log.e("RETROFIT", "ERROR : " + e.localizedMessage)
                    chain.proceed(original)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e("RETROFIT", "ERROR : " + e.localizedMessage)
                    chain.proceed(original)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("RETROFIT", "ERROR : " + e.localizedMessage)
                    chain.proceed(original)
                }
            }
            //            .cache(cache)
            .eventListener( object : EventListener() {
                override fun callFailed(call: Call, ioe: IOException) {
                    super.callFailed(call, ioe)
                }

            })
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)//getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
    }
}
```

The stack trace:

```
2019-08-02 14:15:12.819 4157-4288/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
Process: com.my.app, PID: 4157
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to my_url
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:248)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at com.my.app.network.ApiClient$getRetrofitBuilder$okHttpClient$1.intercept(ApiClient.kt:50)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to my_url (port 80) from /:: (port 0) after 60000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:137)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at com.my.app.network.ApiClient$getRetrofitBuilder$okHttpClient$1.intercept(ApiClient.kt:50) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200) 
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
    at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:118)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:168)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212) 
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436) 
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621) 
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114) 
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at com.my.app.network.ApiClient$getRetrofitBuilder$okHttpClient$1.intercept(ApiClient.kt:50) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200) 
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 19):

Well, that's what I do, just to reduce try-catch junk copypaste

Declare our API call methods like this

```
@GET("do/smth")
suspend fun doSomething(): SomeCustomResponse
```

In a separate file

```
suspend fun <T: Any> handleRequest(requestFunc: suspend () -> T): kotlin.Result<T> {
    return try {
        Result.success(requestFunc.invoke())
    } catch (he: HttpException) {
        Result.failure(he)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
suspend fun doSmth(): kotlin.Result<SomeCustomResponse> {
    return handleRequest { myApi.doSomething() }
}
```

HTTP codes are handled by Retrofit - it just throws an HttpException if responseCode is not 2xx. So what we should do is just catch this exception.

I know, it is not a perfect solution, but let's for Jake to invent something better)

Comment: And if the result is an `Unit`?

Comment: if the result is Unit. It will crash and you might have to create a custom adapter factory to handle the Unit case

Comment: Thanks Arthur, it's worked. But my API's generic response inculde a error message, i want to get error body. How can i return this message with Result.failure, is it possible?

Comment: Good idea @Arthur. But there seems to be some restriction from the jetbrain's Kotlin. Just check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631827/why-cant-kotlin-result-be-used-as-a-return-type

Comment: Exceptions are thrown only for **HttpException**?

Comment: 'kotlin.Result' cannot be used as a return type

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky hoooly, my bad) Fixed it in my code, forgot to update here. But the main concept is still there.

Comment: To bypass a "kotlin.Result cannot be used as a return type" limitation, just do this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53684679/6047716

Comment: If you just want to wrap `try/catch` in `Result`, there is a built-in `runCatching()` function. ;)

Comment: To add to @gmk57 comment, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run-catching.html

Answer (score 6):

You can just add a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` to handle the error for you:

In your ViewModel:

```
val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler{_, t -> {
  t.printStackTrace()
  showErrorOrSomething()
}}

viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + coroutineExceptionHandler) {
   val apiResponse = ApiConnectionBridge.getHomeUiDetails(SharedPrefUtils.getAuthToken(context))
        if (apiResponse.isSuccessful) {
           // success case
        } else {
            // error case
        }
}
```

Comment: can you let me know of some workaround to get error code and error message in this approach? I would appreciate that

Comment: the `apiResponse` should have it. maybe the `body()` or `errorBody`. 

```
apiResponse.code
```

Answer (score 2):

An addition to Arthur Matsegor's answer:

In my case API returns to me an error message for bad requests. For this scenario, i need to catch error message on Catch function. I know, writing try/catch to Catch function looks like ugly but it's worked.

```
private suspend fun <T : Any> handleRequest(requestFunc: suspend () -> T): Result<T> {
    return try {
        Result.success(requestFunc.invoke())
    } catch (httpException: HttpException) {
        val errorMessage = getErrorMessageFromGenericResponse(httpException)
        if (errorMessage.isNullOrBlank()) {
            Result.failure(httpException)
        } else {
            Result.failure(Throwable(errorMessage))
        }
    }
}

private fun getErrorMessageFromGenericResponse(httpException: HttpException): String? {
    var errorMessage: String? = null
    try {
        val body = httpException.response()?.errorBody()
        val adapter = Gson().getAdapter(GenericResponse::class.java)
        val errorParser = adapter.fromJson(body?.string())
        errorMessage = errorParser.errorMessage?.get(0)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        return errorMessage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to the party but I think this is the finest solution:

If you are using **Kotlin + Retrofit + Coroutines** then just use `try` and `catch` for network operations like,

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val userListResponseModel = apiEndPointsInterface.usersList()
            returnusersList(userListResponseModel)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Where, Exception is type of `kotlin` and not of `java.lang`

This will handle every exception like,

1. HttpException
2. SocketTimeoutException
3. FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher etc

Here is my `usersList()` function

```
@GET(AppConstants.APIEndPoints.HOME_CONTENT)
suspend fun usersList(): UserListResponseModel
```

**Note:** 
Your RetrofitClient Class must have this as `client`

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: but is this a right way to do checking on network operation??just confirming...cant we do it with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { //toast for fail
}`  ???????????need explanation ...thanks

Comment: @Wini you can use sealed class for handling response, whether it's error or success.

Comment: Don't catch `Exception` because it will also catch `CancellationException` which is required for normal job shutdown propagation of the coroutines in the scope. Catch specific exceptions instead.

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following in your ViewModel to gracefully handle exceptions:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
   kotlin.runCatching {
      withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
          ApiConnectionBridge.getHomeUiDetails(SharedPrefUtils.getAuthToken(context))
      }

  }.onSuccess { 
       // do something with success response
  }.onFailure{
      // do something on failure response
  }

}
```

Comment: This ain't working. have you tried it before posting here?

Comment: This one works for me ✅, but how can I get the error message coming from the server?

Comment: JSON response from my API server for 404 is {"success": 0, "error": "Data not found."}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps somebody:
Its possible to get rid of the `SocketTimeoutException` in the following way:
1. Set the readTimeout of your client to a arbitrary number, here its 2s

```
 val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
```

2. When doing API calls always wrap them inside a coroutine timeout.

```
  try {
          withTimeout(1000) {
              try {
                  val retrivedTodo = APICall()
                  emit(retrivedTodo)
              } catch (exception: HttpException) {
                  exception.printStackTrace()
              }
          }
      }catch (ex: CancellationException) {
        Log.e("timeout","TimeOut")
      }
```

The main point is, that the **withTimeout** value is smaller than the Retrofit timeout value. This assures, that the coroutine stops being suspended BEFORE the Retrofit timeout kicks in.

Anyway, this is produces many try/catch blocks and is probably not what the retrofit developers wanted, when including the coroutine support.

Comment: This ain't be the solution.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need interceptors for this problem. Wrap the retrofit API call with try/catch like this:

```
suspend fun getHomeUiDetails(authToken: String): Result<HomeDetailsResponse>
        return try {
            val response = yourRetrofitService.getHomeUiDetails(authToken)

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                return Result.Success(response)
            }

            return Result.Error(
                IOException("Error getting details ${response.code()} ${response.message()}")
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Error(IOException("Error getting details", e))
        }
}
```

Comment: There's no function named as Error for the Result class in kotlin 1.3.40. So, i cannot use this method here.