# Server response best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, kotlin, server, backend

I'm developing a RESTFUL web server that have some API REST used by android clients. It's the first time I've done API REST so i followed several guides to made it. Now when client make a GET request to get something, the server return the data in JSON, but not additionals information. Now that I'm making the android application I understand that this type of managment isn't good because i can't handle the errors like 401, 404, etc from application to show errors to the user (I use retrofit 2 with coroutines).
Can someone explain me the best method to make the responses from the server? I understand that I have to make a generic class like **Response** that have a Code and an Error_Message, and I have to extend this class for all my responses to add the data required from the client. But after that how I handle the response from my application? I can't make two different classes (one for errors and one for success responses).
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of solution you propose, is not REST. A common practice in the past was to use only 200 success responses and POST everything. REST APIs by convention use the status codes to convey a meaning. You should also always think of error 500, because this **will** happen and your application **should** handle it.

You also might be interested in this: [Microsoft best-practices api-design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design)

> I understand that this type of managment isn't good because i can't handle the errors like 401, 404, etc from application to show errors to the user

I don't see why you can't do that. There is perfectly good code to handle the requests.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<YourModel> call, Response<YourModel> response) {
    // All the 20x responses
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

    } else if (response.code() == 401) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

You can also use an interceptor, if you are using OkHttp [Check here for interceptor code](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html)

Comment: But i use coroutines (in kotlin) so i don't have the response.isSuccessfull()

Comment: And i want to understand also how to make the response from the server side

Comment: For your first comment, try the last answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323111/kotlin-android-retrofit-2-6-0-with-coroutines-error-handling For your second, I suggest that you don't make the response on the server side. Stick with the error codes and get the messages if you want to create a rest api. Otherwise you'll just create another HTTP api

Comment: I don't understand the second answer, can you be more specific? What do you mean with  " Stick with the error codes and get the messages"

Comment: Keep on sending 400 and other non 2XX codes and extract the message from the exception. Non ok codes come along with a description,

Comment: Now in my asp.net server when something gone wrong I always return `BadRequest("Error message")` and when it success I return `Ok()`.. It's good?

Comment: Not really. Your code should handle more than BadRequest (400). When a GET resource does not exist 404, when the user is not authorized 401 etc. A nice table of indicative response codes: https://bytenbit.com/best-guidelines-design-restful-api/ By bad request, the consumer understands that they should change the request format or values based on some documentation or even better open-api specification.