# How to allow Result<T> to be return type in Kotlin?

Tags: maven, kotlin, kotlin-maven-plugin

I researched an error [Why can't 'kotlin.Result' be used as a return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631827/why-cant-kotlin-result-be-used-as-a-return-type) and want to enable it by `-Xallow-result-return-type`.

I use `kotlin-maven-plugin` and my `pom.xml` build section:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                <!-- Possible solution in order to return Result<T> type bypassing Kotlin developers recommendations -->
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xallow-result-return-type</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As far as I checked [kotlin-maven-plugin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) there is no such an option.

The error I am getting is

> Kotlin: 'kotlin.Result' cannot be used as a return type

Am I doing anything wrong? How to enable `Result<T>` as a return type?

Comment: The Result template is 100 lines long you could just copy it!
Also I am curious of why would you prefer insisting on using this _gadget_ class over throwing the exception or returning null.

Comment: @BenoitGuina First of all, I prefer to use language built-in functions. This specific library allows me to show Railway Oriented programming in Kotlin, so each method will return container and Result<T> is equivalent to Either in Scala. This allows keeping Kotlin null-free in certain scenarios. Copying class and use it is not a problem, maintenance will be an issue.