# Handling exception thrown within a withContext() in Android coroutine

Tags: android, exception, kotlin-coroutines

I have an android app that I have built up an architecture similar to the [Google IO App](https://github.com/google/iosched). I use the `CoroutineUseCase` from that app (but wrap results in a `kotlin.Result<T>` instead).

The main code looks like this:

```
suspend operator fun invoke(parameters: P): Result<R> {
        return try {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                work(parameters).let {
                    Result.success(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Timber.e(e, "CoroutineUseCase Exception on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            Result.failure<R>(e)
        }
    }

 @Throws(RuntimeException::class)
 protected abstract suspend fun work(parameters: P): R
```

Then in my view model I am invoking the use case like this:

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                createAccountsUseCase(CreateAccountParams(newUser, Constants.DEFAULT_SERVICE_DIRECTORY))
                    .onSuccess {
                        // Update UI for success
                    }
                    .onFailure {
                        _errorMessage.value = Event(it.message ?: "Error")
                    }
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                Timber.e("Caught exception (${t.javaClass.simpleName}) in ViewModel: ${t.message}")
            }
```

My problem is even though the `withContext` call in the use case is wrapped with a `try/catch` and returned as a `Result`, the exception is still thrown (hence why I have the catch in my view model code - which i don't want). I want to propagate the error as a `Result.failure`.

I have done a bit of reading. And my (obviously flawed) understanding is the `withContext` should create a new scope so any thrown exceptions inside that scope shouldn't cancel the parent scope (read [here](https://medium.com/@chibatching/avoiding-to-crash-caused-by-misunderstanding-kotlin-coroutine-scope-b38ff5cbef20)). And the parent scope doesn't appear to be cancelled as the exception caught in my view model is the same exception type thrown in `work`, not a `CancellationException` or is something unwrapping that?. Is that a correct understanding? If it isn't what would be the correct way to wrap the call to `work` so I can safely catch any exceptions and return them as a `Result.failure` to the view model.

**Update:**
The implementation of the use case that is failing. In my testing it is the `UserPasswordInvalidException` exception that is throwing.

```
override suspend fun work(parameters: CreateAccountParams): Account {

        val tokenClient = with(parameters.serviceDirectory) {
            TokenClient(tokenAuthorityUrl, clientId, clientSecret, moshi)
        }

        val response = tokenClient.requestResourceOwnerPassword(
            parameters.newUser.emailAddress!!,
            parameters.newUser.password!!,
            "some scopes offline_access"
        )

        if (!response.isSuccess || response.token == null) {
            response.statusCode?.let {
                if (it == 400) {
                    throw UserPasswordInvalidException("Login failed. Username/password incorrect")
                }
            }
            response.exception?.let {
                throw it
            }
            throw ResourceOwnerPasswordException("requestResourceOwnerPassword() failed: (${response.message} (${response.statusCode})")
        }

        // logic to create account

        return acc
    }
}

class UserPasswordInvalidException(message: String) : Throwable(message)
class ResourceOwnerPasswordException(message: String) : Throwable(message)

data class CreateAccountParams(
    val newUser: User,
    val serviceDirectory: ServiceDirectory
)
```

**Update #2:**
I have logging in the full version here is the relevant details:

```
2020-09-24 18:12:28.596 25842-25842/com.ipfx.identity E/CoroutineUseCase: CoroutineUseCase Exception on main
    com.ipfx.identity.domain.accounts.UserPasswordInvalidException: Login failed. Username/password incorrect
        at com.ipfx.identity.domain.accounts.CreateAccountsUseCase.work(CreateAccountsUseCase.kt:34)
        at com.ipfx.identity.domain.accounts.CreateAccountsUseCase.work(CreateAccountsUseCase.kt:14)
        at com.ipfx.identity.domain.CoroutineUseCase$invoke$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutineUseCase.kt:21)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
2020-09-24 18:12:28.598 25842-25842/com.ipfx.identity E/LoginViewModel$createAccount: Caught exception (UserPasswordInvalidException) in ViewModel: Login failed. Username/password incorrect
```

The full exception is logged inside the catching in `CoroutineUseCase.invoke`. And then again the details logged inside the catch in the view model.

**Update #3**
@RKS was correct. His comment caused me to look deeper. My understanding was correct on the exception handling. The problem was in using the `kotlin.Result<T>` return type. I am not sure why yet but I was somehow in my usage of the result trigger the throw. I switched the to the `Result` type from the Google IO App source and it works now. I guess [enabling its use as a return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631827/why-cant-kotlin-result-be-used-as-a-return-type) wasn't the smartest.

Comment: Can you add the definition of method work() with question ?

Comment: Added the usecase definition @ADM. The main work is done inside requestResourceOwnerPassword() it is not a `suspend` function

Comment: I reduced my use case down to a single line `throw UserPasswordInvalidException("This is a test. It should always fail")` and the exception is still propagated to the view model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try/catch` inside `viewModelScope.launch {}` is not required.

The following code is working fine,

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class TestCoroutines {

    private suspend fun work(): String {
        delay(1000)
        throw Throwable("Exception From Work")
    }

    suspend fun invoke(): String {
        return try {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                work().let { "Success" }
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            "Catch Inside:: invoke"
        }
    }

    fun action() {
        runBlocking {
            val result = invoke()
            println(result)
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    TestCoroutines().action()
}
```

[image]

Please check the entire flow if same exception is being thrown from other places.

Comment: I updated with some log output to show the flow. The exception being caught `UserPasswordInvalidException` in the view model is only thrown in one place in the code.