# Accessing optional kotlin.Result

Tags: kotlin

```
val ld: LiveData<Result<Int>>? = getLiveDataFromSomewhere()
ld.value?.let { // expression of type kotlin.Result cannot be used as a left operand of '?.'
}
```

Why can't a `Result?` be unwrapped via the ?. operator? Is this another bizarre restriction like "kotlin.Result cannot be used as return type", that can be suppressed with some Gradle directive?

UPDATE: I have already added the `-Xallow-result-return-type` flag to build.gradle. Results can be used as return types now. This is a different issue.

Comment: Read the quote in the top answer here. Both using it as return type and using nullability operators with it have the same restriction with the same rationale. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631827/why-cant-kotlin-result-be-used-as-a-return-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't 'kotlin.Result' be used as a return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52631827/why-cant-kotlin-result-be-used-as-a-return-type)

Comment: @Steve, I've already added the `-Xallow-result-return-type` compiler arg, and I can return Results now. This is a different issue.

Comment: Ok.  I'll take your word for it then.